# Search and replace contents of yanked text in vim

Tags: search, vim, replace, clipboard

In my vimrc, I have a shortcut to copy the filename with its path to the clipboard.

```
:nmap cp :let @* = expand("%")
```

This works fine. Now, I want to replace the contents of this yanked text to

```
1) replace \ with /  
2) remove certain words from the yanked text.
```

I am familiar with search and replace on regular text but I don't know how to change my vimrc entry to do this every time on the yanked text when I use my shortcut.

So, something like this?

```
:nmap cp :let @* = expand("%") || %s/\\/\/ || %s/<word>//
```

I am using gvim on windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `:substitute` command works on the buffer contents itself; that's not so useful here. (You could temporarily `:put` the register / file name, transform it, and then `:delete` it (back) into a register.) Fortunately, there's an equivalent low-level [`:help substitute()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) function that you can apply on a String:

```
:nnoremap cp :let @* = substitute(expand("%"), '\\', '/', 'g')<CR>
```

In fact, `expand()` directly supports a special substitution [`:help filename-modifiers`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers), so this would be a (rather obscure) solution, too:

```
:nnoremap cp :let @* = expand("%:gs?\\?/?")<CR>
```

For the additional removal of `<word>`, you can use another layer of `substitute()` / append another `:gs???`. I'll leave that to you.

#### Additional critique

- Your mapping is missing the trailing `<CR>` to conclude command-line mode.
- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- `%` is relative to the current working dir. If you need the full absolute path, you can get that via `%:p`.
- Starting your mapping with `c` is unconventional. It's fine here, because the `c`hange command wants a `{motion}`, and `p` is not a valid one. In general, I'd rather avoid such clever overloading (as long as you have other unused mapping prefixes still available).

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I used substitute and expand. It works fine.

    substitute(expand("%:gs?\\?/?"),'<word>','','g')<CR>

Thank you for the critique. I've fixed them also.